# How to rename a table in mysql using variables to generate the new table name?

Tags: mysql, sql

This is my code to rename the table.

```
SELECT  @MinDate := MIN(time) FROM trans;

SELECT  @MaxDate := MAX(time) FROM trans;

set @NewTableName := CONCAT(@MinDate, '-' , @MaxDate );

RENAME TABLE trans To @NewTableName;
```

In this I'm getting error like

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '@NewTableName

I don't know what is the error.

Answer (score 3):

Use dynamic sql

```
set @q = concat("rename table trans to", @newtableName);
prepare stmt from @q;
execute stmt;
deallocate prepare stmt
```

Comment: In mysql 5.5, the second line should be `prepare stmt from @q;`

Answer (score 0):

rename is a atom operation, I don't think you can use sql variable here.